# How to add condition for removeLabel in github actions?

Tags: github-actions, github-issues

Using [actions/importer-issue-ops](https://github.com/actions/importer-issue-ops/) Template and using multiple Runners with matrix strategy (`ubuntu-latest`,`selfhosted-runner`)

In the Cleanup step using below yml script to `removeLabel` for an `issue`.

```yaml
     - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: always() 
        with:
          script: | 
             await github.rest.issues.removeLabel({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              name: 'actions-importer-running'
             });
```

As we are using multiple runners the `ubuntu-latest` runner code able to identify the label and deleting properly, whereas `selfhosted-runner` failed to delete because it was already deleted by `ubuntu-latest`.

Error message:

```
RequestError [HttpError]: Label does not exist
Error: Unhandled error: HttpError: Label does not exist
```

Trying to add condition to verify the label and deleting, looking for the solution to add some condition which will verify the label and initiate `removeLabel` if exists.

Thanks in advance!

Tried [octokit/rest.js](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v19) and other available actions but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can add a condition e.g. `if: ${{ matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest' }}` to remove label from one specific runner only.

Comment: Thank you @azeem but the runners are often changing and suppose to not set hardcoded values any suggestions.

Comment: Well, you can first get the label to make sure it exists and then delete it. Or, you can simply mark these steps [`continue-on-error: true`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error). Or, you can get the result from that API call, analyze its result, log properly, and just return a success status as not to fail it.